# How delete a selected character on the texbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't make a code to delete a selected character on the texbox.
*Example: I would remove ",H"
"H,t,I,P,H,A,P"
Result:
"H,t,I,P,A,P" (only 1 ",H" must be removed)*
I tried with Contains and remove does not work
no other that I have found

```
string source = Texbox.Text;

if (source.Contains(',H'))
{
   source.Replace(",H", "");
}
```

Does not work at all.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: What is exact logic to remove a character? does it remove from the end of string or start of the string?

Comment: is your source string is always comma separated ?

Comment: `string.Replace()` returns result with removed string, have you tried `source = source.Replace(",H", "");`

Comment: `source = source.Replace(",H", "");` should do it. You need to assign the value to your string.

Comment: What is exact logic to remove a character? =found a solution fixed my pb. 
does it remove from the end of string or start of the string? = From  the end
is your source string is always comma separated ?=Yes

Comment: source = source.Replace(",H", ""); should do it. You need to assign the value to your string.
I thought it worked too.
but no.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove in general an H then this:
`string MyString = "Hello World!"; char[] MyChar = {'e', 'H','l','o',' ' }; string NewString = MyString.TrimStart(MyChar); Console.WriteLine(NewString);`

otherwise you loop throught locate its index and use this :
`string MyString = "Hello Beautiful World!"; Console.WriteLine(MyString.Remove(5,10)); // The example displays the following output: //         Hello World!`

in your case:

```
Console.WriteLine(Texbox.Text.Remove(9,1));
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question asked - I tried your first example & the result was just "World!" - it didn't just remove the letter "H". Applying your solution to the OPs original string the result is ",t,I,P,H,A,P" which is not what is expected. Applying your second idea to the original string results in "H,t,I,P,HA,P" - again not what was expected.

Comment: I confirm, that neither solution works.
Does anyone have another idea?